# what else do i need to see in return of the phpinfo() for a PDO connection to work?

Tags: pdo, php

this is the part of the result of my phpinfo where i could find the word pro?

```
PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version    5.0.45
```

strangely i got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

additional to this i didn't have a "localhost" in my config file.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked. In a very strange way the connection established after i changed the order of the attributes of the pdo connection statement.

Here is the connection before change (i go this order from http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php):

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name.'', $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("set names utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then i tried to change the order of it like this:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host.'', $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("set names utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

And now it worked. I guess this issue comes from the hosting company.

Comment: This is apparently not the case and the hosting company is not to blame. Also, you have been told to get rid of all the try .. catch blocks but still have them in place, keeping debugging as hard as you had it before.

Comment: yes i did what you told before @YourCommonSense but i didn't get any response at all. the error reports are off. so i added the try catch back but i tried it. the only way it works was this way above. i don't know perhaps during my tries something thing else changed on the server. but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need mysql server running on localhost, I believe.
Or any other mysql server to connect to.

Use search and replace feature in your editor and get rid of all the try .. catch blocks in your code. It will help you find the actual place where you're connecting to localhost instead of the proper mysql host.

Comment: but this hosting company has a lot of sql servers and the now they gave me has a different ip not localhost.

Comment: Welll, use them instead of localhost

Comment: I am using the provided ip as host right now but i get the error.

Comment: no i am running the config.php directly. and in the config file there is just the database connection.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you *think* you're running. The error is clear and unambiguous: you are trying to connect localhost somewhere in the code.

Comment: okay i will clean the whole folder and create one single file for the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP and pdo are correctly installed and configure.

I think you didnt setup your database username and password correctly

More infos available on the official MySQL website:

http://lists.mysql.com/myodbc/10475

Comment: i am able to login to the phpmyadmin panel with the current credentials.